# Oracle how I can group by duplicate value of a column into an other column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-view

I have an oracle VIEW that contains some duplicates value inside a column I want to group those duplicates values for each row inside an other column this my VIEW:

```
myView : 

---------------------------
ID  | col 1       | col 2  |
---------------------------
1   | P1          |V1
2   | P1          |V1
3   | P1          |V2
4   | P1          |V3
5   | P2          |t1
6   | P2          |t1
7   | P2          |t2
```

I want to create an other view based on myView that will contains values like this :

---

```
ID  | col 1       | col 2  |col 3
---------------------------------------
1   | P1          |V1      |V1,V1,V2,V3
2   | P1          |V1      |V1,V1,V2,V3
3   | P1          |V2      |V1,V1,V2,V3
4   | P1          |V3      |V1,V1,V2,V3
5   | P2          |t1      |t1,t1,t2
6   | P2          |t1      |t1,t1,t2
7   | P2          |t2      |t1,t1,t2
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `listagg()` as a window function:

```
select t.*,
       listagg(col2, ',') within group (order by col1) over (partition by col1) as col3s
from t;
```

Comment: Don't we need to add partition by clause. and what if duplicates have to be ignored

Comment: This solution give me in the col3 values like  : V1,V1,V2,V3,t1,t1,t2 for each row

Comment: @ErrabiAyoub . . . It needs a `partition by`.

Comment: Yes the partition by resolve the problem it's work ! thanks Man

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, col1, col2, LISTAGG(col2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col1) OVER (PARTITION BY col1) as col3 
from myView;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.